# Ошибка при исполнении systemctl status ezstream

Tags: icecast

Устанавливаю ezstream. В процессе установки ввожу команду `systemctl status ezstream` и получаю следующее:

```
● ezstream.service - ezstream
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/ezstream.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2023-07-15 15:45:26 MSK; 2min 48s ago
   Main PID: 11555 (code=exited, status=217/USER)

systemd[1]: ezstream.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
systemd[1]: Stopped ezstream.
systemd[1]: ezstream.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
systemd[1]: ezstream.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
systemd[1]: Failed to start ezstream
```

Я подумал, что не выдал нужные права файлу /etc/icecast2/ezstream.xml, но

```
ezstream[11768]: /etc/icecast2/ezstream.xml: world readable
ezstream[11768]: stream: default: no configuration
```

Файл /etc/icecast2/ezstream.xml:

```
<ezstream>
<url>http://ip_адрес/stream</url>
<sourcepassword>hackme</sourcepassword>
<format>MP3</format>
<filename>/music/playlist.m3u</filename>
<shuffle>0</shuffle>
<playlist_program>0</playlist_program>
<svrinfoname>Name</svrinfoname>
<svrinfourl>http://ip_адрес/stream</svrinfourl>
<svrinfogenre>Ofther</svrinfogenre>
<svrinfodescription>Description</svrinfodescription>
<svrinfobitrate>128</svrinfobitrate>
<svrinfochannels>2</svrinfochannels>
<svrinfosamplerate>44100</svrinfosamplerate>
<svrinfopublic>1</svrinfopublic>
<reencode>
<enable>1</enable>
<encdec>
<format>MP3</format>
<match>.mp3</match>
<decode>lame -f --preset cbr 128 --bitwidth 16 "@T@"  -</decode>
</encdec>
</reencode>
</ezstream>
```

Что делать в данной ситуации?

Comment: Ну например читать полные логи, а не один лишь status